# Add a form with 2 buttons into a hbox dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

Let's say I have this function

```
function Do(x:String){}
```

How can I make so that each time this function is called, it will add a form into a hbox, and that form will have 2 buttons yes and no and put x into the text of a label.

When the user is going to click on Yes I need to trace(x) and remove the Form from the hbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a lot of addChild methods. This should get you started:

```
var newForm:Form = newForm();
var yesBut:Button = new button();
var noBut:Button = new button();
var label:Label = new Label();

newform.addChild(yesBut);
newform.addChild(noBut);


yesBut.AddEventListener(MOUSE_EVENT.Click,yesFunction);
noBut.AddEventListener(MOUSE_EVENT.Click,noFunction);

label.name = "myLabel";
label.text = x;
```

//create your yes and no functions

```
private function yesFunction(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var x:String = event.currentTarget.parent.getChildByName("myLabel").text;
    trace(x);
    hbox.removeChild(event.currentTarget.parent);
}
```

This is off the top of my head, so some of it may need to be worked a little to function properly

Comment: how do you send the x from the Do() to the yesFunction() ?

Comment: I edited my response I missed that you were passing X as an argument.

Comment: hmm, I see, I think that is going to work, but is there a better way of getting the value of x beneath getting it from the value of the label ?

Comment: AFAIK, When you add event listeners you can't pass any arguments (other than the automatic event argument) to the handler function. So you have to assign x to some variable somewhere so that you can reference it.

Comment: can I inherit the form add a custom field where I can store the x ?